# eclipse won't create adt project due to 'access denied'

Tags: android, windows-7, access-denied

I installed JavaEE, JDK,  Eclipse 3.5.x (Galileo), the Android Starter SDK, and the current ADT all with no problems.  However, when I try to walk through the 'Hello Android' tutorial, I bring up the New Android Project wizard, fill it in and hit 'Finish'.

After a moment, it comes back with a message saying there was a problem at path X:\so and so\ (access denied).

Things to note:
    -Running Windows 7 Home Premium  64-bit
    -Quadcore Pentium with 8GB RAM, 8TB NAS
    -I am an Administrator
    -I have also tried this by activating the full (hidden) Administrator profile
    -I have reinstalled everything 8 or 9 times
    -I have changed ownership & permissions all over the place
    -I have launched eclipse in 'Run as Administrator' Mode
    -I have installed Everything as 32-bit, as others have done this successfully

Eclipse creates the folder it's having a problem with, but then cannot work with the .project file it creates (access denied).  It then can't save anything so there is nothing but an empty folder 'Hello_Android' on the left within Eclipse.

Anybody have any clues about what is going on-- I'm frustrated.  I want to get into this, and I've looked EVERYWHERE on the net trying to crack this nut.... but I need help.

-J

Comment: This is more of a question for superuser.com I would say.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. Interesting.

I would double-check permissions on the folder X:\so and so\ and ensure that the Administrators group and/or your account has full control.

Comment: I have completely reworked the permissions many times, even from the NAS to be sure I have full control.  My user account is an Administrator.  I have also unlocked the real Administrator account and tried it.  No change.  I have 'Full Control' on all files, folders, and subfolders.  I have also run Eclipse using 'Run as Administrator'.  No change.  I also confirmed that UAC is set to the lowest (essentially 'off' they say) setting, and rebooted.  No change-  it STILL asks me if I want to run eclipse every time I launch it because it's not certified.  stupid uac.

Comment: Ah. So, X: is mapped to a NAS share? My next suggestion would have been to try creating a project in a workspace on a local drive and see if you have the same problem. According to your other comments, it looks like you've done that already. What do you mean when you said "it still asks e if I want to run ecipse every time I launch it because it's not certified"?

Comment: Another option is to use MOTODEV Studio (http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/motodevstudio/download/). It's based on Eclipse Pulsar (shouldn't make a difference, but worth a try). It has a full installer. When you run it for the first time, it prompts you to install an SDK. I'm on Widows 7 Ultimate 64-bit (UAC at default setting) and MOTODEV Stuido and haven't experienced the issues you are.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating the project outside of the users or systems environment? You know in c:\myprojects

Windows7 and creating/saving files in program files or documents can be a PITA.

Comment: I create the project in X:/ a NAS.  Both eclipse and Android SDK run in the same folder hierarchy, NOT in programs, not on C:\.  I did originally try running them from within the programs (32-bit) folder, but that yielded identical results.  I've tried creating the projects folder on C (various places) as well, including /users/nyname, and still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a bug with how eclipse is written.  I've developed a workaround.

Comment: I'm curious. What is the workaroud? What is the issue? How did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that eclipse can't write to hidden files, unhide them and it should work.